# jQuery mobile panel transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page with a jQuery sliding menu, how can I control the menu sliding transition.
For example to change the sliding speed?
Here is my code:

```
<div id="navpanel" data-role="panel" data-theme="a" data-display="push" data-position="right">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false">
            <button id="main">Main</button>
            <button id="business">Business</button>
            <button id="numbers">Numbers</button>
            <button id="money">Money</button>
            <button id="people">People</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note: I need only panel transition control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/pZzrk/

```
.ui-panel-animate {
    transition: transform 1350ms ease 0s !important;
}
```

Unfortunately transition speed can't be changed through configuration so **`CSS`** overriding is needed here.

Original value is **`350ms`**.

Comment: It works good in chrome browser, but on android devices there is a little delays.

Comment: There's always a delay on Android devices. This is the same CSS uses inside a jQuery Mobile class to initialize transition.